# How to make Travis go build faster when using modules

Tags: go, go-modules

We use go modules and travis for a project. Every time Travis builds the project,  go modules fetch all of the dependencies which increases the build time. Is there any way to reduce that time or avoid fetching the deps every time?

Comment: Consider [vendoring your dependencies](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-do-i-use-vendoring-with-modules-is-vendoring-going-away). See also [the referenced blog post specifically for Travis](https://arslan.io/2018/08/26/using-go-modules-with-vendor-support-on-travis-ci/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can cache the Go modules to speed up the build process.

```
- language: go

  script:
    - your script

  cache:
    directories:
      - $HOME/.cache/go-build        # Cache the binaries
      - $HOME/gopath/pkg/mod         # Cache the Go modules
```

Reference : https://restic.net/blog/2018-09-02/travis-build-cache

Comment: Which approach is the correct approach to go for it? Caching or vendoring?

Comment: There is no "correct" approach. The two options do different things. Which do you want?

Comment: I am trying to avoid vendoring if it is possible and make build faster in Travis.